# How do I show the weather of Provided Coordinates ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openweathermap

I have a code that fetches details of a farm with the longitude and the latitude. Now I want to get the weather of that particular farm using `openweathermap`

When I try, I am getting an error `{cod: '400', message: 'wrong latitude'}` on my console.

Here is my code. How can I get the weather correctly, or at least how can I call the latitudes and longitudes correctly.

`

```
function FarmDetails() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    const [farm, setFarm] = useState({});
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
    const { username } = useParams();
    const { farmId } = useParams();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {

        let isMounted = true;

        axios.get(`/api/farm/${username}/${farmId}`).then(res => {
            if (isMounted) {
                if (res.data.status === 200) {
                    setFarm(res.data.farm);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    console.warn(res.data.farm)
                }
                else if (res.data.status === 404) {
                    navigate('/');
                    toast.error(res.data.message, "error");
                }
            }
        });

        return () => {
            isMounted = false
        };
    }, []);



    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${farm.latitute}&lon=${farm.longitude}&appid=[APIKEY]&units=metric`)
            .then((result) => result.json())
            .then((weather) => {
                setWeather(weather);
            });
    }, []);

    console.warn("result", weather)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have a typo in your code: `farm.latitute` is probably supposed to be `farm.latitude`.

Comment: Thanks, but after correcting that, I am getting another error :  `{cod: '400', message: 'Nothing to geocode'}`

Comment: Shouldn't your weather `useEffect` only work when `farm` has been updated? You should add `farm` to its dependency array, and then check its existence within the effect itself. @JohnMark